# Class generics - decide inside of method which type to return

Tags: java, generics

This might be a silly question but.. Let's say i have some method. This method might have a generics return type (or not), but.. i want that this method will decide which class to return. Meaning it is not known at time of calling the method. Example:

```
public <U> SomeWrappingClass<U> execute() {
  if (..) return new SomeWrappingClass<Foo>();
  else return new SomeWrappingClass<Bar>();
}

SomeWrappingClass c = obj.execute();
c.barMethod() // in case of SomeWrappingClass<Bar> returned
c.fooMethod() // in case of SomeWrappingClass<Foo> returned
```

I guess it doesn't work like that and type must be known at moment of method call. Maybe only via some member of returned object, or via call of Runnable with generics as parameter of method? Eg

```
public SomeReturnObject execute() {
  SomeReturnObject o = new SomeReturnObject();
  if (..)
    o.returnObj = new SomeWrappingClass<Foo>(); 
  else 
    o.returnObj = new SomeWrappingClass<Bar>(); 
}
```

Now i can call o.returnObj.barMethod() in case of SomeWrappingClass

Edit: ResultObject is not a solution too, (at least ResultObject with generics like ResultObject< T >) because it is same situation as without it).. so.. unless return the class somehow.. so the caller will know the class.. but that's not possible again with eg Class< T > as it must be known at moment of call.

Comment: Could you use `SomeWrappingClass<?>`?

Comment: <?> means i can decide inside the method what to return?

Comment: @luky <?> means that the caller never can know what exactly will be returned

Comment: In that case he would be ok with Object as return type

Comment: @luky Yes, it will allow you to choose the generic type from within the method. It will not give the caller the information of which specialisation is used by the returned `SomeWrappingClass`. However, using this, the compiler will provide you some kind of guarantees which you would not have if you used a raw `SomeWrappingClass` or `SomeWrappingClass<Object>`. For instance, if I have a list `List<?>`, the compiler will not allow to add any object to it _after_ the list has been constructed, e.g.: `List<?> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()` and then `list.add(1)` is forbidden.

Comment: The interest of using this `<?>` is therefore limited, and may not be what you want for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

All you do about generics matters only at compile-time, not at run-time.

So, if at compile-time you don't know whether it's `SomeWrappingClass<Foo>` or `SomeWrappingClass<Bar>`, then you have to declare the common denominator that matches both cases, e.g. Alexandre's suggestion SomeWrappingClass

Or, if you have a common superclass or interface for Foo and Bar, then you can use `SomeWrappingClass<? extends SuperFooBar>`.

Of course, your caller will not know whether it's `SomeWrappingClass<Foo>` or `SomeWrappingClass<Bar>`, not at compile-time nor at run-time. So if it makes a difference to your caller's logic, you have to provide a way for him to distinguish (but that's a "code smell").

One additional possibility:

Introduce subclasses `FooWrappingClass extends SomeWrappingClass<Foo>` and `BarWrappingClass extends SomeWrappingClass<Bar>` and return instances of these classes. Then you can put specific behaviour there.

Comment: This is why interfaces exist. I would suggest interfaces instead of extending. `Interface MyFooBarBaz { public void executeFooOrBarOrBaz();}`